# Parse exception with simpleDate Format

Tags: java, date

I am trying to convert date from one format to other format but the following code is giving me the exception: please help

```
public class Formatter {
        public static void main(String args[]) {

            String date = "12-10-2012";
            try {
                Date formattedDate = parseDate(date, "MM/dd/yyyy");
                System.out.println(formattedDate);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public static Date parseDate(String date, String format)
                throws ParseException {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
            return formatter.parse(date);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To convert from **"MM-dd-yyyy"** to **"MM/dd/yyyy"** you have to do as follows:

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = format1.parse("12-10-2012");
System.out.println(format2.format(date));
```

If you input `"12-10-2012"` then output will be `"12/10/2012"`:

Answer (score 6):

change slash `/` to dash `-`

**MM-dd-yyyy** instead of **MM/dd/yyyy**

it should be `Date formattedDate = parseDate(date, "MM-dd-yyyy");`

Answer (score 5):

Your format uses slashes (/) but the date you supply uses dashes (-). Change to:

```
Date formattedDate = parseDate(date, "MM-dd-yyyy");
```

And you should be good :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Date formattedDate = parseDate(date, "MM-dd-yyyy");
```